# Typescript: Map properties from one object to another

Tags: typescript

I have the following two types and object.

```js
type TypeA = {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
};
type TypeB = {
  d: number;
  e: number;
  c: number;
};
oldObject: { [key: string]: TypeA };
```

I want to map the properties from an object of type `TypeA` to an object of type `TypeB`. So far I've come up with the following.

```js
const newObject: { [key: string]: TypeB } = {};

Object.entries(oldObject).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  newObject[key] = {
    d: value.a,
    e: value.b,
    c: value.c,
  } as TypeB;
});
```

Is there any way of doing this in typescript with something like a map or reduce function? I would much prefer to not have to assign `{}` to `newObject` at first.

Comment: There is no easy way to achieve that using `map` or `reduce` since they works only on arrays and not object. Converting you object to an array would be an anti-pattern and objects don't guarantee property order? according to ES5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```
type TypeA = {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
};
type TypeB = {
    d: number;
    e: number;
    c: number;
};

declare const oldObject: { [key: string]: TypeA };

const newObject: { [key: string]: TypeB } = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(oldObject).map(([key, value]) => [
        key,
        {
            d: value.a,
            e: value.b,
            c: value.c
        }
    ])
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8CwAoKuoEMAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcBubPKK486uxnPAYzcpoNsAXy6hIseACEU6JngAm-DkO64IywV2Z9SAziK7YFEHgBt8taDwD2JAM7AoNswoDyVAFangxNFABtAGsIEGJHWgBLEgBzAF1iOEgkUWxsWwcnEggAdw9vHl90QJCwqAjo+MTpKGFZfJ8AOgAzWhsKAFESYCiIewAKeVwGwsaIbt6Bl3cvHwBKRop8MH7+4NCAGigAN3wzMgg4uZQAPkCh5ihSjYvmTDVL5iUdvYPG-BuHx-ViXf2IRpUT7fS66P5vHi3PDCC5HbBzehAA)

To elaborate a little, `Object.fromEntries` is, as its name suggests, the inverse of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), taking an array of `[key, value]` elements and creating an object where the keys are mapped to their corresponding values.

Thus, we start with `Object.entries` as before but, instead of using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to populate our new object, we [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array, transforming each `[key, value]` to `[key, newValue]` and  pass the resulting array to `Object.fromEntries`.

Note that, as jcalz remarks, `Object.fromEntries` was introduced in ES2019. If your target runtime does not support ES2019, you will need to add a polyfill such as [npm:object.fromentries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.fromentries) and correspondingly specify `"lib": ["ES2019"]` or higher in your `tsconfig.json`

I've removed the type assertion `as TypeB` since it is both unnecessary and would more importantly would suppress errors like forgetting or misspelling a property declared by `TypeB`. Type inference is one of TypeScript's most important aspects.

Your intuition around using `map` and `reduce` is a very natural one. Not only have we used `map` here, but `reduce` was frequently used to achieve the same result as `Object.fromEntries` before the latter was introduced.

Comment:  You might also want to mention that the target environment needs to support ES2019 for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use lodash's mapValue

```
const oldObject = {
  x: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  y: { a: 11, b: 22, c: 33 },
}

function map(value) {
  return {
    d: value.a,
    e: value.b,
    f: value.c
  };
}

const newObject = mapValues(oldObject, map);

console.log(newObject);
```